# What languages should be used to make a live updating waterpolo scoreboard website

Tags: web

I wish to make an electronic scoreboard for my school's water polo team. They requested it to be in a from of a website.

This scoreboard has a front and back end, the front end showing the live scores, players on etc while the back end allows the scorekeeper to adjust the data on the front end.

The front end updates the moment when the data in the back end is changed. If possible, the front end is to be viewable by multiple users.

What language (s) should I be using in addition to HTML to create the front end?

It seems like this "Comet" thing is the best use, but how should I get started with Comet?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC or WebForms, take a look at [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr). It is open source library that makes developing real-time web functionality easy.